# 301 Moved Redirect Htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm just wondering how I can do a 301 moved redirect in the htaccess to redirect

```
site.com/music/the-search-term_8f2ea1.html
```

to

```
site.com/download/mp3/1/the-search-term.html
```

(note the _8f2ea1 needs to disappear, will always have a _ infront of it)

if anyone could help me that would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^music/(.*)_(.*).html http://site.com/download/mp3/1/$1.html [R=301,L]
```

did the trick

Comment: Not sure how it worked since RewriteRule can only match URI. You cannot find and match `site.com` in RewriteRule.

Comment: sorry, yeah i accidentally put that in there when i posted this, fixed it now.